# Why was I removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-accounts

I hovered on my name and it had written on it:-
-5 user was removed.

Can anyone explain what happened?
thanks.

I tried to see the name.

Comment: As the answer below states, it was not you who was removed, but some other user who must have upvoted one of your questions.  [Read here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/214632) for more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You weren't removed. What it means is that a user who had previously up-voted you has been removed. When a user gets removed, all the reputation they have given out is cancelled; from looking at your profile, it seems that someone up-voted one of your questions (giving you 5 points) and then their account was deleted.

Comment: ok Thanks , I got it:)